# Get the specific custom parameters value inside column name

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a possible way to get the value from a custom parameter inside a column.

As you can see in the picture below. I have a column name Parameters, and has a value of custom parameters.

1.) Is there any way that I can only get the price and its corresponding value inside that column name?

2.) Is there any possible way to decipher the format?

3.) Can you give me a idea how to parse it accordingly?

Click this to see the picture

[image]

Im just curious guys. Thanks in advance for those who will helping me out.

Comment: Try this :: select * from your_table where parameters REGEXP 'price<=>[0-9]';

Comment: can i use less than or greater than? inside ' '? for example if the price is <= 1000? @skelwa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string pattern always starts like 'price<=>' (i.e. 9 characters in start). You can use below query to check the price and compare it.

The inner query uses substring to find the price value from matching rows. Outer query can be used to perform comparison as you want.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(parameters, 9) AS price
    FROM
        your_table
    WHERE
        parameters REGEXP 'price<=>[0-9]') t
WHERE
    price > 1000;
```

Comment: what if sir I only want to output is only (price<=>7897) and not all the custom parameters inside parameters column name?

Comment: If you want complete column to be printed, then you can use : 
SELECT  * FROM your_table WHERE parameters REGEXP 'price<=>[0-9]';